# Save PDF when clicked on a download button without showing the OK/Cancel option to save

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible not to show Open/Save dialog? I would like to save the pdf file straight to specific disk location on client PC. Need in NOdeJS
I am automating a LogIn in NodeJS which after a successful login, on clicking a 'Download Report' should download the pdf directly to the computer. On manually testing it does so. However when i run my script after clicking the 'Download Report' it would give a javascript popup for confirmation to save. –

Comment: I believe this is a browser setting. This isn't something that can be controlled by the website.

Comment: Agreed. However even if you do the browser setting when the webdriver opens the new Firefox window it still shows the Save OK option as per the old setting. I had handled this in Selenium Webdriver however am not able to do the same in NodeJS.

Comment: FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); // MIME type for zip file "aaplication/pdf" // setting for automatic download of the Neilsens Pdf report. profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false); profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pd‌​f"); profile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types","application‌​/pdf"); profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true); // 0 = desktop, 1 = default download folder , 2 = user defined location. –

Comment: Ah, you are using selenium to automate this. That changes things. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After reading your comment again, I noticed you are adding some settings to your profile that sound like they should make it do what you want. Since it isn't working, I think it would be good for you to try what I describe below.
END EDIT

You stated in a comment that you are using Selenium Webdriver to do the login automatically, and the download popup only appears when Selenium is driving the browser. The reason it doesn't keep your settings (to not show the popup) when Selenium is in control, is that Selenium creates a new profile, which has the default settings. You will need to manually create a profile for your browser (I see you are using Firefox), open Firefox with that profile, change the settings to not display the download popup, and tell Selenium to use that profile when it runs.

I'm not sure what your environment is, but I run Selenium from linux, so to create a new profile, I run Firefox from the command line with a `-P` flag, which opens the profile manager. If you use windows, you may need to look up another way to do this.

Once you have the profile created, and have changed the settings appropriately, change your code to the following:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("path/of/firefox/profile"));
```

Hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: Thankyou. I understand what you are saying and i had done the FF profile setting when i automated the same using Sel Webdriver. I was asked to convert this code to NOde JS and I dont know how to do the profile setting thru Node.